# Crash after accessing a deleted object : Deletion first time gives The thread 0x2164 has exited with code 0 (0x0) on console

Tags: c++, multithreading

Since, this is my office-code, i would not be able to show any code. Apologies for that. Hopefully, i would be able to explain my problem.

I have an application where i get notifications. On one close-notification, i delete my object and unregister from the notification.

I am using visual-studio and have put up console-print-function name and some variable when a function is hit without stopping. When i play with my app, i see a crash. I have a vector with some objects, the vector is usually of size 1.

On looking through the console log i find that whenever, my app works fine, i see three messages showing the size of vector before and stack-trace in destructor of object and size of vector after the deletion of object. This is like 1 and some stack and 0, since i remove the object.

However, at the workflow of crash, i see only the first message with size 1, then i see the stack trace that i put in the destructor of object but no message with size 0. However, there are other lines with :

```
The thread 0x2164 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1734 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x670 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1b20 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2310 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1f40 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x164c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x15fc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I have enabled the "Exception handling/reporting in Visual Studio" but do not get any exception.

The result is that app get the notification again, and app try to access the object again, it crashes.

I do not understand how to begin solving this problem ?

Comment: i guess stack is getting corrupted.

Comment: Maybe place code to check if you are accessing a valid object.

Comment: Well, how is it possible to find whether object is valid or not. as soon as i access it,app would crash.

Comment: You dont have to access it to see if its memory location is valid. A simple assert(object != NULL) would do.

Comment: this object is being pointed by multiple pointers.. no use of setting pointer to NULL.